# Flutter Chat Application, Check for changes in the API (Django-Rest-Framework)

Tags: django, post, flutter, get, chat

I have built a chatt App using Django And Flutter, so I do a get request to get the information, also a post request from any user in the chat room to send new information(chats).

My Question is how do I detect changes in the api? Is it possible to update let's say every 10 seconds, also have a pull to refresh, and just call a new get request on those? Also just Make a get request right after the post request so you can se your own messages?